# Copy and transform a file using Node.js

Tags: node.js, file-io, template-engine

I want to copy some files using Node.js. Basically, this is quite easy, but I have two special requirements I need to fulfill:

1. I need to parse the file's content and replace some placeholders by actual values.
2. The file name may include a placeholder as well, and I need to replace this as well with an actual value.

So, while this is not a complex task basically, I guess there are various ways how you could solve this. E.g., it would be nice if I could use a template engine to do the replacements, but on the other hand then I need to have the complete file as a string. I'd prefer a stream-based approach, but then - how should I do the replacing?

You see, lots of questions, and I am not able to decide which way to go.

Any hints, ideas, best practices, ...?

Or - is there a module yet that does this task?

Comment: dead simple approach: read the entire file and use regexes

Comment: @mihai Even if the file is 30GB big?

Comment: well he didn't give any details about the nature of the file :)

Comment: No, the files aren't 30 GB big. Anyway I though there may be a more elegant approach than loading everything to memory. This is why I thought of streams.

Comment: @mihai That's why it's safe to assume that the file might be big. Anyway, I'd also like to know if there's any stream-based solution to this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own solution without reading the entire file. `fs.readFile()` should only be used when you are 100% sure that the files are no longer than a buffer chunk (typically 8KB or 16KB).

The simplest solution is to create a readable stream, attach a `data` event listener and iterate the buffer reading character by character. If you have a placeholder like this: `${label}`, then check if you find `${`, then set a flag to true. Begin storing the label name. If you find `}` and flag is true then you've finished. Set flag to false and the temporal label string to `""`.

You don't need any template engine or extra module.

Comment: But you do need to handle 'placeholders' that cross chunks. I.e. the `$` might appear in chunk _n_ and the `{` character in chunk _n+1_.

Answer (score 1):

If the whole file can be safely loaded into memory (isn't crazy big), then the library [fs-jetpack](https://github.com/szwacz/fs-jetpack) might be very good tool for this use case.

```js
const jetpack = require("fs-jetpack");

const src = jetpack.cwd("path/to/source/folder");
const dst = jetpack.cwd("path/to/destination");

src.find({ matching: "*" }).forEach((path) => {
  const content = src.read(path);
  const transformedContent = transformTheFileHoweverYouWant(content);
  const transformedPath = transformThePath(path);
  dst.write(transformedPath, transformedContent);
});
```

In the example code is synchronous, but you can easily make async equivalent.